# JavaScript. code not executed. UI not updated

Tags: javascript, user-interface

when a line of code that updates the user interface is executed BEFORE of a block of code that keep the system busy for a while, the UI is not updated.
Please see the code below:

```html
 <html>
   <body>
    <div id="acc">
       <input type="text" value="start" id="id1"/>
       <input type="text" value="e0" id="id2"/>
    </div>
    <script>
      myFunction();
      function myFunction() {  
         document.getElementById("id1").value="1";
         var j=true;
         for(var i=0;j==true;i++){
            document.getElementById("id2").value="e"+i;  
            if(i==999999)
             j=false;
         }
         document.getElementById("id1").value="2";
       }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The value 1 is never assigned to the input text (id1).
It's like if the JavaScript code is not executed synchronously.

Does someone can help on this?

Comment: `1` is not assigned to `id1` because you're assigning  `2` to it right after the `for` loop

Comment: yes but the loop is taking 10 seconds. I should see 1 while is looping.

Comment: @Marc, you misunderstand The screen is not updated until the javascript has finished executing....

Comment: thank you, isn't this a bug?  How can I remediate to this?

Comment: @Marc Javascript execution isn't synchronous. And it's single-threaded. Replace the `for` loop with `setInterval` or a recursive `setTimeout` if you want to see the values changing on your screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make your code async, like this;

```html
 <html>
   <body>
    <div id="acc">
       <input type="text" value="start" id="id1"/>
       <input type="text" value="e0" id="id2"/>
    </div>
    <script>
      myFunction();
      function myFunction() {  
         document.getElementById("id1").value="1";
         setTimeout(function(){
            for(var i=0;i<=999999;i++){
               document.getElementById("id2").value="e"+i;  
            }
            document.getElementById("id1").value="2";
          },5);
       }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The screen is updated after every event is completed (javascript executes in an event loop).  So when the setTimeout function is executed the screen is updated once it is finished regardless of how long time it has taken.  Only one event is executed at any time, so if there is more events they get queued up until the previous event is finished.

Answer (score 1):

The value is updated, it's just that the *screen* is not updated until the JavaScript execution is complete (JavaScript execution locks the UI). The added console.log will print what you expect:

```
myFunction();

function myFunction() {
    console.log(document.getElementById("id1").value); // outputs "start" as expected
    document.getElementById("id1").value = "1";
    console.log(document.getElementById("id1").value); // outputs "1" as expected
    var j = true;
    for (var i = 0; j == true; i++) {
        document.getElementById("id2").value = "e" + i;
        if (i == 999999) j = false;
    }
    document.getElementById("id1").value = "2";
}
```

One solution is to split up the loop into "chunks". Say we run 1000 iterations at a time, then using `setTimeout` we schedule the next 1000 iterations to run after 1ms. We repeat this until we have looped over the entire set:

```
myFunction();

function myFunction() {
    // iterator which we count up each loop
    var i = 0;

    // set to initial value
    document.getElementById("id1").value = "1";

    function processDone() {
        document.getElementById("id1").value = "2";
    }

    function processChunk() {
        var maxLoopsPerCall = 1000;
        while (maxLoopsPerCall-- > 0) {
            document.getElementById("id2").value = "e" + i;

            // if we're done, we call our done function and call return (so we don't schedule any more chunks
            if (i == 999999) {
                processDone();
                return;
            }

            i += 1;
        }

        // schedule to process next chunk of the loop
        setTimeout(processChunk, 1);
    }

    // schedule to process the first chunk of the loop
    setTimeout(processChunk, 1);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8kddxqmd/

Comment: thank you #Strille, isn't this a bug? How can I remediate to this?

Comment: As other answers have pointed out, you need to split up the loop into smaller chuncks using setInterval or setTimeout. That way the UI will have a chance to update since each JavScript execution will not take any significant time. Or at least have a delay before the loop so that the UI has had a chance to update the input with the value "1".

Comment: @Marc: I've added an example how to split up the loop into "chunks", hope this clears things out.

Answer (score 1):

You may try using `window.setInterval()`

```js
var id1 = document.getElementById("id1");
var id2 = document.getElementById("id2");
id1.value = 1;
var i = 0;
var t = setInterval(function() {
  if (999999 < i) {
    clearInterval(t);
    id1.value = 2;
  }
  id2.value = 'e' + i;
  i++;
}, 6);
```

```html
<input type="text" value="start" id="id1" />
<input type="text" value="e0" id="id2" />
```